# Azure remote computer to VS code Error: Internal extension error: Token acquisition parameters cannot be read from extension context. Please try again

Tags: python, azure, visual-studio-code, virtual-machine

I am trying to connect my Azure ML compute remotely to my VS Code but am suddenly getting an error:

```
Error: Internal extension error: Token acquisition parameters cannot be read from extension context. Please try again
```

Would anyone be able to help me understand why this is happening? Happy to give any more information required but not sure where this is coming from.

Comment: What extension prompted this message?

Answer (score 0):

- I have tried to Create and connect the Compute Resource from VSCode, Initially I got Conflict error with Azure Machine Learning Extension.
- Re-Installed the `VSCode` and added the Azure Machine Learning Extension
- Created Compute Resource from portal and connected remotely from VSCode.

***Check the below workaround***

- In Azure Portal create a Compute Instance in `Azure Machine Learning Resource`
- From Overview Section = > Launch Studio
  [image]
- Under Manage section Select Compute and Create
  [image]
- In VSCode =>Machine Learning Extensions=> My Subscriptions => Compute Resource => Click on New and Create a New Compute Resource

[image]

- Click on VSCode in Applications ,VSCode will be launched.
- In ***VSCode*** , Open the Machine Learning Extension and select your newly created compute Instance.Right click and connect.

[image]

- It takes some time to refresh and load the Created Instances

Refer [Connect to an Azure Machine Learning compute instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-set-up-vs-code-remote?tabs=extension#configure-a-remote-compute-instance)  for more information